# Spring MVC HandlerInterceptor hack

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I had to publish a results on our website, which were to be published on particular time. So I wrote a spring interceptor which will not allow the request to go through before specified time. I have also maintained logs of the results catered successfully.

Everything worked fine for me except some request logged before time. Which means somebody managed to bypass the interceptor and could see the result before time.

Can anybody tell me, how the intruder sees the result before time?
I am using Spring MVC and Spring JDBC in my application.

Interceptor –

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class ResultTimeCheckerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private Date resultPublishTime;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        long currentTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        if (currentTime < resultPublishTime.getTime()) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("resultNotPublished").forward(request, response);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    public Date getResultPublishTime() {
        return resultPublishTime;
    }

    public void setResultPublishTime(Date resultPublishTime) {
        this.resultPublishTime = resultPublishTime;
    }
}
```

Servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure --> 

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />


    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="result" />


    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="propertyEditorRegistrars">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="result.propertyeditor.CustomDateEditorRegistrar" /> 
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <mapping path="/" />
            <mapping path="/result" />
            <beans:bean
                class="result.intrceptor.ResultTimeCheckerInterceptor">
                <beans:property name="resultPublishTime" value="${result.publishTime}" />
            </beans:bean>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
    <context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:property/application.properties" />
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: "Everything worked fine for me except some request logged before time." - could you please elaborate this a bit more. (what kind of request)

Comment: As per the logic in the interceptor  all requests to “/” and “/result” should be intercepted and if the current time is less than specified time (1 PM)  then the request should be forwarded to different page where “The result will be published on 1 PM” message was displayed. 
If the request comes after 1 PM it should display the result after logging the request time.
The logic worked fine for me.  But the log says somehow the hacker could see the result before 1 PM

Comment: again: which url was invoked by the "hacker"?

Comment: /result which returns the result of the candidates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

- `http://localhost:8080/yourApplication/result`  -- should been "blocked"
- `http://localhost:8080/yourApplication/result.html`  -- should been "blocked" but mybe it does not
- `http://localhost:8080/yourApplication/result/`  -- ? depends on you
- `http://localhost:8080/yourApplication/result/x`  -- ? depends on you too